# Why are converter methods in Java Library classes non-static?

Tags: java, java-8

I see that several converter methods in Java Library classes are non-static. Example : toEpochMilli() of Instant, toArray() of ArrayList. We can instead have static methods like toEpochMilli(Instant instant) and toArray(ArrayList arrayList) to achieve the same purpose, right? Is there any specific reason why these methods are non-static?

Comment: So instead of `myList.toArray()` you want to write `ArrayList.toArray(myList);`?

Comment: Uh, yes, the whole point of having objects and polymorphism is that usually you don't make stuff static unless this really is the only thing that makes sense.

Comment: For the same reason we have instance methods in the first place. Let us ask the other way round: why do you think, they should be static? You didn’t name any reason.

Comment: Can you tell us what you think the benefit of having those methods `static` would be? I can't imagine one right now...

Comment: "pure methods" - I assume you mean pure functions, don't you? You should realize that Java is an object oriented language and while it got some functional components lately it's still not a functional language (and probably never will be).

Comment: If those converters are static methods, they are pure methods. That means, they don't depend on anything except the arguments passed to that method.

Comment: @J.Dow likewise, `toArray()` doesn't depend on anything except for the list it's working on.

Comment: Let's make sure we agree on the definition of a "pure" method: _A method is pure if it always returns the same result for same argument values and it has no side effects._ So are you saying that only `static` methods can be pure?

Comment: There are external libraries like Google Guava which does this.

Comment: @Malt Yes, it is more like an utility method and utility methods are usually static.

Comment: Whether you use `a.foo(b)` or `foo(a, b)`, the input are `a` and `b`. So in either case, `foo` is pure, when it returns the same result for the same `a` and `b`. Though, I don’t know how it applies when calling `toArray` on a mutable collection. Not to speak of the fact that `toArray` on an `ArrayList` is implemented totally different than `Collections.emptyList()`’s or `HashSet`’s methods. Which is the genuine reason to declare it as an overridable instance method.

Comment: @Abra I think the term "pure" has caused quite a bit of confusion here. Apologies for that. I've removed it from the question. What I am trying to understand here is that why are those methods non-static when we can achieve the same by those methods being static.

Comment: Well, you could achieve the same with static methods but they'd still have to operate on instance methods like `size()` or `iterator()` to actually build an array. But using static methods would lose the advantage of optimized implementations, e.g. `ArrayList.toArray()` can be much more efficient than `LinkedList.toArray()`.

Comment: So when you removed the “pure” term, you ended up again by not naming a single reason for why these methods should be `static`.

Comment: My reasoning is that when you can achieve the same with a static method, why to make it non-static? Rules for making a method static are mentioned here : https://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2013/07/when-to-make-method-static-in-java.html

Comment: If you list all the static methods of `Instant`, you might notice the rule the designers of JDK followed: static methods are factory methods, everything else is instance-scoped. You don't want to put utility methods in a non-utility class. You don't want to mix up utility methods and factory methods in one class. You may want to use dynamic polymorphism. You may want to call both instance and static methods.

Comment: “when you can achieve the same with a static method”… Can you? `static` methods are independent of the actual implementation class, as there is no dynamic dispatch, which contradict s your examples which *do* depend on the implementation. Now that `default` methods exist, development goes into the other direction, like with `Collections.sort(List, …)` which is now superseded by `List.sort(…)`, to take the benefits of instance methods.

Comment: @AndrewTobilko in case of `Instant`, there’s not even polymorphism. However, there’s still no reason why anyone should *want* to have to write `TypeOfA.method(a…)`, when `a.method(…)` is possible as well. Which directly leads to the exhibited pattern, as in case of factory methods, or any method where no instance is available, a `static` method is unavoidable. For everything else, there is no reason to use a `static` method.

Comment: @Holger no reason, but we still had (and have) `Collections.sort` (which became obsolete since `List#sort`)

Comment: @AndrewTobilko of course, we can’t just remove a widely used method, but nowadays, `Collections.sort` just delegates to `List.sort`.

Answer (score 4):

In [a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58623605/why-are-converter-methods-in-java-library-classes-non-static#comment103555343_58623605), you wrote:

> Yes, it is more like an utility method and utility methods are usually static

which seems to reflect the mindset of your question very well. There are two problems with it. For one, there is no clear definition of “utility method”, which makes this categorization very subjective.

Second, the fact that utility methods are (or were) often implemented as `static` methods does not indicate that this is an actual design pattern that should be copied, just because it has been done that way before.

This is rather a historic compromise. Before Java 8, there were no `default` methods, so every method added to an interface had to be implemented, even if only by delegating to another helper method.

As a practical example, if `sort` was added to the `List` interface right at the beginning, every `List` implementor had to deal with it. So it was rather added as [a `static` method to the `Collections` class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort-java.util.List-java.util.Comparator-) which does not imply that anyone considered

```
Collections.sort(list, comparator); // no import static by that time
```

better than

```
list.sort(comparator);
```

Or that having a one-size-fits-them all implementation. Not only did this miss optimization opportunities for implementations like `ArrayList`, it also implied that erroneously applying it to an immutable list would stay unnoticed when the list happened to be in the right order.

Now that we have `default` methods, `List` has [such a `sort` method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#sort-java.util.Comparator-), so implementors are still not required to deal with that, but they *can* override the method when it is appropriate. So `ArrayList` has an optimized version, immutable lists throw unconditionally and the implementation returned `Collections.synchronizedList` can make the entire operation synchronized.

The categorization as a “utility method” never played any role here. Note that other languages deal with it differently, e.g. via Extension Methods, which have their pros and cons on their own, but also show that having to write an invocation of a utility method as a `static` method is not an actual goal. Actually, it’s the opposite.

Answer (score 0):

Static does not work as well with inheritance:

```
List<String> list1 = new ArrayList<>();
List<String> list2 = new LinkedList<>();

list1.size()
list2.size()
ArrayList.staticSize((ArrayList) list1)
LinkedList.staticSize((LinkedList) list2)
List.staticSize(list1); // NOT POSSIBLE
```

One would want something like:

```
interface List {
    static staticSize(List list) {
        return list.size();
    }
}
```

But then still a non-static `size()` is used.

There is no static dispatch, polymorphism. (The JVM has some support, for other languages.)

Comment: A non-abstract interface method is either `default`, `static`, or `private`. Not a combination of `default` and `static`. Besides that, a dispatch mechanism for a static method based on the first argument would be an ordinary virtual call with just a differently looking syntax.

Comment: @Holger was intended as pseudo-code, impossible. A static method in a class/interface not being able to be directly backed by a static method in an extending/implementing class. This makes a static method in ArrayList senseless.

Comment: Well, `static` methods in interfaces are supported, but there is no dispatch algorithm based on the first argument (the actual `List` implementation). And, as said, if it existed, it would be nothing but an instance method by another name.